# Tell users a site has moved

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've moved a site to a new domain at a new ISP. I want to tell people about the change if they use the old URL because I don't know how long it will be available.

I can do that easily using htaccess to redirect all old domain requests to a landing page that provides the requested URL as a query parameter. The landing page can then tell the requester the URL has changed and provide a link to go to the same page at the new domain.

That approach helps the requester but doesn't use a 301 redirect and I don't think a link can do that. As I understand it, 301's are now the only way to tell the main search engines of a domain change.

I could instead redirect the old domain to the new one with a 301 but I can't find a way to tell the requester the domain has moved. If I could detect the redirection, I could add an information block to the top of the destination page when it occurs.

I can access referrer at the new site but I understand referrer is unreliable and would, in any case, be blank for a stored link.

I could add a query parameter, say ?isredirected=true to the 301 address but I understand search engines will include the query string version in search results and try to differentiate it from the same address without the query parameter.

I understand that adding a user-defined header variable will be ineffective because the browser will ignore it when actioning the redirect.

I could use the user agent to detect a crawler and redirect thos requests using 301 and others using the landing page but that could get me into hot water with the search engines.

I could move the old domain to the new ISP and leave it there, but I'm uncertain the old ISP can/will cooperate (it seems to have disappeared even though the server is still running) and that would, in any case, incur additional cost for a not-for-profit organisation with very little income.

Any better ideas?

Comment: Can you `301` to `newdomain.com/the-path?redirected=true` and set a cookie, then `301` again to `newdomain.com/the-path` and then use the cookies presence to show a message?

Comment: That's devious, but a great idea. I've implemented that using 302 redirects for now in case of problems, but it seems to be working well.

When I generate the cookie I give it a value of the target url and a time stamp. I show the 'We've' moved' heading only if a page finds the cookie, sees its own address and the cookie was generated less than 30 seconds ago. That prevents the heading from appearing on the wrong page or if the user navigates back to the target page.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue for us, but worth noting that the 'we've moved' header will appear only the first time a given page is redirected. After that, the 301's will cause the page to redirect to the new page without dropping a cookie.

I think I'll drop the check for a matching page and up the time limit to, say, 10 minutes to give the reader enough time to see and respond so the header.

Comment: _"but I understand search engines will include the query string version in search results and try to differentiate it from the same address without the query parameter"_ - yes, a different query string means they _are_ different URLs; but you can tell search engines what the "real" URL is supposed to be, by specifying the canonical URL. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element

Comment: >>>you can tell search engines what the "real" URL is supposed to be, by specifying the canonical URL<<<
Thanks for that. As i happens, my WordPress template automatically adds that link element to every page automatically which has already confused Google since there can be multiple paths to the same content. Fortunately the above solution allows me to by-pass that issue.

Answer (score 0):

The double 301 solution worked fine for us. After less than 24 hours since we started using 301's Bing is already showing the new domain at the top of relevant searches. Google hasn't reacted so quickly but is showing links to the new domain without the 'redirected' query string.